# Issue with bounding box in octomap_server

Tags: ros, octomap, octomap-mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When running the octomap_server it sometimes crashes during a map update. This is the error message that is returned:

*virtual void Map3D::handlePreNodeTraversal(const ros::Time&): Assertion `mapUpdateBBXMaxX > mapUpdateBBXMinX' failed*

During testing I noticed that this happens when large open spaces are encountered. I'm wondering if anyone else also encountered this and what the best way is to deal with this.

Thanks!

---

**Update:** I indeed had set the `~incremental_2D_projection parameter` to true

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50618/issue-with-bounding-box-in-octomap_server/) by [bcoenen](https://answers.ros.org/users/3802/bcoenen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2012-12-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2012-12-17**:
Which version of octomap_server is that, in which ROS release?

**Comment by [bcoenen](https://answers.ros.org/users/3802/bcoenen/) on 2012-12-18**:
It's version 0.4.5 under the Fuerte release

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sorry for the late reply, for some reason I did not get an email notifying me of the update / comment...

There is an experimental feature to incrementally update the 2D projected map, instead of regenerating all of it.  This may be the culprit since it's not completely tested. However, the default for the parameter `~incremental_2D_projection` should be false, did you enable it?

There should be a debug output "Rebuilding complete 2D map" for octomap_server, in that case mapUpdateBBX... is not used.

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2012-12-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1